# Include proxy settings into system connections files

Tags: ubuntu, network-interface, proxy

I have following connection that my system connects to

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections$ ls
connection1 connection2 connection3
```

one which I have to use proxy settings, let say `connection1`. Is there a way to set proxy settings inside `connection1` file so I need not to enable/disable proxy settings from **GUI** each time I connect to one of these networks? I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.